# Transparent background, picture with border in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, border, transparent, gimp

I would like to ask, how to create a border for graphics, which I cut from original picture in Gimp (or other program. I'm caring about method).

When I have this random shapes graphic, with transparent background, how to give the border just for THIS graphic? CSS make border for previous, original size of the picture.

I'm using Gimp and save like a .png or .gif

Comment: So you would like to e.g. give a border to an image of a hexagon shape with transparent background? In a way that the border would follow the hexagon's perimeter? As far as I know this isn't possible since the border is applied to the image's box model, which has a maximum of 4 borders.

Comment: I want to cut something from the picture and add the dotted border just for this specific shape. So, You say It is not possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use *Image>Autocrop image* to reduce your image to the smallest rectangle that contains all the non-transparent bits.